# Error in getting text from edittext-Android 2

Tags: android, textview

I'm doing a currency converter and i want to only introduce one value and that value is transform in the coins that the user want. When i run the program and click on the bottom to convert it closes the application and in the logcat appears the error- java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference.

I dont know where the error is and i'm a begginer in android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


int money1, money2,money3,money4;
int[] money = {money1,money2,money3,money4};
int from;
TextView rate;
Button button1;
EditText ed1; 
EditText ed2; 
EditText ed3;
EditText ed4;
Spinner spinner1;
Spinner spinner2;
Spinner spinner3;
Spinner spinner4;


EditText[] values = {ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4};


 String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN                          FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};
String[] simbol = { "AOA", "ARS", "AMD","AWG","AUD","BYR","BOB","BRL","KHR","CAD","CNY","EUR",
          "INR","JPY","CHF","THB","GBP","USD","VND","LYD"};

 int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
        R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
        R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
        R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
        R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
        R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);





Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) 
        findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));  

Spinner mySpinner1 = (Spinner) 
        findViewById(R.id.spinner2); 
mySpinner1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));  

Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinner3); 
mySpinner2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues));

Spinner mySpinner3 = (Spinner) 
findViewById(R.id.spinner4); 
mySpinner3.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnerValues)); 

 button1.setOnClickListener(this);




  } 

 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
 { public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) 
 { super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects); } 

 @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
 { return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt); }

 @Override 

public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
{ return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt); } 

 public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
 View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

  String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN   FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



    int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
    main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

     ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
      left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
     return mySpinner;

     }
     public View getCustomView2(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
      View mySpinner1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

      String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



     int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner1 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

     ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner1 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
       left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
     return mySpinner1;}

      public View getCustomView3(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
      View mySpinner2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

     String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



     int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

     TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner2 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

       ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner2 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
       left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
       return mySpinner2;}

      public View getCustomView4(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      { LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
       View mySpinner3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);

       String[] spinnerValues = { "ANGOLAN KWANZA" , "ARGENTINE PESO" , "ARMENIAN DRAM" , "ARUBAN FLORIN" , "AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR" , "BELARUSIAN RUBLE" , "BOLIVIAN BOLIVIANO" , "BRAZILIAN REAL" , "CAMBODIAN RIEL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE YUAN RENMINBI","EURO","INDIAN RUPEE","JAPANESE YEN", "LIBIAN DINAR","SWISS FRANC","THAI BAHT","BRITISH POUND","US DOLLAR","VIETNAMESE DONG"};



    int arr_images[] = { R.drawable.angola, R.drawable.argentina,
    R.drawable.armenia, R.drawable.aruba, R.drawable.australia,
    R.drawable.bielorussia, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil,
    R.drawable.cambodia, R.drawable.canada, R.drawable.china,
    R.drawable.eur, R.drawable.india, R.drawable.japan,
    R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.swiss, R.drawable.thai, R.drawable.uk,
    R.drawable.us, R.drawable.vietnam };

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner3 .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
     main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);

    ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner3 .findViewById(R.id.left_pic); 
    left_icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 
    return mySpinner3;}


     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
     }



      void getRate(int from, int to) {
        String currency;
       String currency2;


        currency2 = simbol[from];

        int i;

     for (i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        to=money[i];
         currency=simbol[to];



       GetExchangeRate httpRate;  
       httpRate = new GetExchangeRate(currency, currency2);
        Thread thr = new Thread(httpRate);
        thr.start();

       }}}

  private void writeRate(final String text) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=3;i=i+1){
        values[i].setText(text); 

  }
}
   });
    }

   private String readStream(InputStream in) {
     BufferedReader reader = null;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      try {
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String line = "";
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    }
   }
      catch (IOException e) {
      return e.getMessage();
   }
       finally {
       if (reader != null) {
          try {
         reader.close();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    return e.getMessage();
       }
     }
    }
   return response.toString();
   } 

   private String transform(String rate) {
   String readableRate = null;

   JSONObject json;
    try {
   json = new JSONObject(rate);
   readableRate = " " + json.getDouble("rate");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
     readableRate = e.toString();
    } 
     return readableRate;  
    }


   //**************************************************************************
  //Internal class to call HTTP operation in a separate thread

   private class GetExchangeRate implements Runnable {
     String currency;
   String currency2;

     GetExchangeRate(String toCurrency, String fromCurrency) {
      currency = toCurrency;
        currency2= fromCurrency;

      } 

     @Override
     public void run() {
URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {
  url = new URL("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + currency2 + "&to=" + currency);
  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

  int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
  if(responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    response = transform(response);
    writeRate(response);
  }
  else
    writeRate("Code: " + responseCode);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  writeRate(e.toString());
} 
finally {
  if(urlConnection != null)
    urlConnection.disconnect();

}
}
}


   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {



    money1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition())); 
money2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition()));
money4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItemPosition()));

int[] money = {money1,money2,money3,money4};
int i;

for(i=0; i<=3;i=i+1)

    if(values[i].getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){

            from=money[i];
            return;}

 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if(values[i].getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
```

`values[i]` is `null` for at least an `i` value, therefore the `getText()` is called on a `null` reference. Try to initialize the elements in `values` first. Check your initialization of `ed1`, `ed2`, `ed3` and `ed4`.

Comment: I dont know whot you mean!!  I've inicialize in               EditText[] values = {ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4};    @Lajos Arpad

Comment: You were setting the elements in your values array with ed1, ed2, ed3 and ed4 BEFORE you have initialized them, thus the values array holds four null references when you loop it.

Comment: Now doesn't appear any error but when i put a value in one edit text and click on the botton to convert nothing happen! Can anyone help me? And thanks @Lajos Arpad

Comment: I do not see the current version of your code, but my instincts tell me that ed1, ed2, ed3, ed4 and the elements in values might be mixed up. I believe the solution might be to initialize ed1, ed2, ed3 and ed4 and just after that initialize the values array. You might have already done so. I hope you will not suffer too long with this issue, good luck and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You initialize values array with nulls at line

```
EditText[] values = {ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4};
```

At this point ed1, ed2... are not initialized. And you fill the array with nulls. Actually, you don't need ed variables. Just replace lines

```
ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
...
```

With

```
values[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: Now doesn't appear any error but when i put a value in one edit text and click on the botton to convert nothing happen! Can anyone help me?  And thanks @user3390963

Comment: I put one value on one edittext and on the other edittexts should appear the value converted to the coin that is choose in the respectevity spinner.

Comment: when i put values[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); in all of the editText how i should inicializate the array values? @ user3390963

Comment: Method findViewById returns already initialized EditText. So, there is no need to do something else. But if you want set text in current EditText, then you just need to call values[0].setText("something").